# Simulating Click with ReactTestUtils not working

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs

I'm trying to write a test using Jest and ReactTestUtils only. How can I simulate clicks correctly? I don't want to use enzyme and stick to what CRA gives me from default.

Button was a stateless component (function) and cannot mount it correctly, but now is a class and still not working the "Simulate" line...

```
`import React from 'react';
import * as TestRenderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import ReactTestUtils from 'react-dom/test-utils';

import { Button } from '..';

let renderer: TestRenderer.ReactTestRenderer;
let instance: TestRenderer.ReactTestInstance;

const button = <Button text="TextButton" />;

describe('Button', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    renderer = TestRenderer.create(button);
    instance = renderer.root;
  });

  it('renders with correct props', () => {
    const buttonProps = instance.findByType('button').props.children;

    expect(buttonProps).toBe('TextButton');
  });

  it('executes onClick function', () => {
    const clickHandler = jest.fn();
    const element = ReactTestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
      <Button onClick={clickHandler} />,
    );
    const buttonElement = 
      ReactTestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag(element, 
      'button');

    // This line returns 'undefined'
    ReactTestUtils.Simulate.click(buttonElement);

    // Returns: Expected mock function to have
    // been called one time, but it was called zero times
    expect(clickHandler).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
})`
```

Any idea? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's your `Button` implementation. But below example works for me.

`Button.tsx`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export interface IButtonOwnProps {
  text: string;
  onClick(): void;
}

export class Button extends Component<IButtonOwnProps> {
  public static defaultProps: IButtonOwnProps = {
    text: '',
    onClick: () => {}
  };
  public render() {
    return <button onClick={this.props.onClick}>{this.props.text}</button>;
  }
}
```

`Button.spec.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import TestRenderer, { ReactTestRenderer, ReactTestInstance } from 'react-test-renderer';
import ReactTestUtils from 'react-dom/test-utils';
import { Button, IButtonOwnProps } from './Button';

describe('Button', () => {
  let testRenderer: ReactTestRenderer;
  let instance: ReactTestInstance;
  beforeAll(() => {
    testRenderer = TestRenderer.create(<Button text="TextButton" />);
    instance = testRenderer.root;
  });

  it('renders with correct props', () => {
    const buttonProps = instance.findByType('button').props.children;
    expect(buttonProps).toBe('TextButton');
  });

  it('executes onClick function', () => {
    const clickHandler = jest.fn();
    const element = ReactTestUtils.renderIntoDocument<IButtonOwnProps, Button>(<Button onClick={clickHandler} />);
    const buttonElement = ReactTestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag(element, 'button');
    ReactTestUtils.Simulate.click(buttonElement);
    expect(clickHandler).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

Unit test result with coverage report:

```sh
PASS  src/stackoverflow/52887470/Button.spec.tsx
  Button
    ✓ renders with correct props (4ms)
    ✓ executes onClick function (14ms)

------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File        |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files   |      100 |      100 |    66.67 |      100 |                   |
 Button.tsx |      100 |      100 |    66.67 |      100 |                   |
------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.076s, estimated 5s
```

Here is the completed demo: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/52887470